# label text change to call for pageload/ javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

basically i got no idea to starts so i cant provide any better code
i have a null label

```
lblErrorMsg = "" ;
```

once if there are any error, my label will display error msg with css

```
lblErrorMsg.Text = "some error Msg";
```

at the same time i am trying to display another image label as well, but i dont want to make it like button click then display the error msg, due to this is an on-going project, so there are lot of button, so what i want to ask is, is there any method can perform during page load to detect label text change?

something like

```
pageload(){
    check lblErrorMsg
    if(lblErrorMsg.Text!=""){
         lblImg.Visible= true;
     }else{
         lblImg.Visible= false;
     }
}
```

Comment: why not if(errorHappens()){lblErrorMsg.Visible= true;lblImg.Visible= true;} ?

Comment: to sajanyamaha, this is what i want, the lblErrorMsg is so called error happen~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript/Jquery for that. Listen to onload  event and do the logic.

You can try putting this in the script tag of your aspx page

```
        window.onload = function(){
            var element = document.getElementById('<%=lblErrorMsg.ClientID%>');
            var lblMsg = document.getElementById('<%=lblImg.ClientID%>');
            lblMsg.style.display='none';
            if(element.innerHTML.length)
                 lblMsg.style.display = 'block';             
        }
```

Comment: hi Akhil, my image label doesnt display~

Comment: the sequence is incorrect, once i clicked the button and reflect, my lblErrorMsg is still null ~

Comment: @CheemunLow ,it seems you have put visible="false" as default in server aspx page code,remove that first.

Comment: yes,i do but the sequence is it run the pageload first, then button clicked, then page load (windows onload detected, at the same time lblErrorMsg is still null) then only come to button event (put some text inside)

Comment: @cheemunLow, Sorry i was out for lunch

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblAttention" runat="server" CssClass="AttentionImg" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
          

        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" CssClass="ErrorMsg"></asp:Label>

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblAttention" runat="server" CssClass="AttentionImg" style="display:none"></asp:Label>

Comment: if became the image will always visible ~

Comment: No. Once you set display:none, it will be hidden

Comment: it never hide, i felt weird as well~

Comment: akhil sekharan, this issue rise me another problem, my submenu items cannot display now T_T

Comment: oops, i meant just now i facing another problem which is my submenu item doesnt display, but i solved it, just due to my body inside has call another onload method >_<

Answer (score 0):

Please put the jquery script and use the below code snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($("#lblErrorMsg").text()!=""){
     $("#lblImg").css("visibility","hidden");
 }else{
     $("#lblImg").css("visibility","visible");
 }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: hi sridhar, i think my problem remain the same, it run pageload first then only put text into the label~